# Pairing Collections in Linq without a For Loop

Tags: c#, linq

I have two collections

```
int[] numbers = {5, 2, 1, 5};
string[] words = {"flibble", "bobble", "double", "dumble"};
```

I want to use a linq expression on the second collection using the first.  Using a loop I'd do the following

```
List<string> results = new List<string>();
for(int i = 0; i<numbers.Count(), i++)
{
  results.Add(words[i].SubString(numbers[i]);
}
return results;
```

However this involves creating a list for no real reason... is there a way to do this in Linq?

Comment: _"However this involves creating a list for no real reason"_ But your desired result is a `List<string>`, isn't it?

Comment: See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/07/zip-me-up.aspx for an explanation of how to write a generalized zip join efficiently, should you ever need to.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I apologise it's not actually - that's my simplified example... I just want an IEnumerable, hence the linq.

Comment: Also, pro tip: if you know that its an array, use `numbers.Length`, not `numbers.Count()`. The jitter can sometimes generate slightly better code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm guessing you're looking for [`Enumerable.Zip()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx):

```
numbers.Zip(words, (n, w) => w.Substring(n));
```

Comment: woah, never saw Zip before, very nice

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
var res = words.Select((str, i) => str.Substring(numbers[i]))
```

Comment: This is a great alternative if you're not on .NET 4.5!

Comment: @Liath what happended in 4.5 ?? :)

Comment: @Liath: Enumerable.Zip was added in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to `Zip` which avoids pitfalls(wrong length or different number of items in the collections)

```
IEnumerable<string> result = numbers
.Select((len, i) => {
    string word = words.ElementAtOrDefault(i);
    if (word != null)
    {
        word = word.Length >= len ? word.Substring(0, len) : word;
    }
    return word;
});
```

Result: `flibb,bo,d,dumbl`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/rwTCzr)